# Differentiable Hamming Loss for TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

The Hamming Loss counts the number of labels for which our prediction is wrong normalizing it.

[image: Hamming loss]

The standard implementation of the HammingLoss as a metric relies on counting the wrong predictions, with something along these lines: (on TF)

```py
count_non_zero = tf.math.count_nonzero(actuals - predictions)
return tf.reduce_mean(count_non_zero / actuals.get_shape()[-1])
```

Implementing the Hamming Loss as an actual loss requires it to be differentiable, which is not this case due to the `tf.math.count_nonzero`.
An alternative (and approximated) method would be counting the non-zero labels in this way, but unluckily the NN doesn't seem to improve.

```py
def hamming_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true, name="y_true")
  y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred, name="y_pred")

  diff = tf.cast(tf.math.abs(y_true - y_pred), dtype=tf.float32)

  #Counting non-zeros in a differentiable way
  epsilon = K.epsilon()
  nonzero = tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.abs( diff / (tf.math.abs(diff) + epsilon)))

  return tf.reduce_mean(nonzero / K.int_shape(y_pred)[-1])
```

Concluding, what's the correct implementation of the Hamming Loss for TensorFlow?

[.1] https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01044994/document

Comment: TF Addons is considering adding this, check [Add hamming loss for both multiclass and multilabel #305](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/305)

Comment: @Xarvalus Unluckily it's implemented as a metric and not as a differentiable loss function

Answer (score 0):

Your network doesn't converge since:

```
diff / (tf.math.abs(diff) + epsilon)
```

yields a `0 , 1` vector which kills the gradients both on zeros and ones